# Repeatedly Calling a Function vs Performing IF in every validation

Tags: oracle, validation, plsql, oracle11g

I created two functions in Oracle 11g R2. They return boolean value according to my test condition. I have used that whenever I am checking for the validity of that condition. However a few of my colleagues are suggesting that I should use an if statement for comparison rather than calling a function, as it would cause more context switching, reducing the overall effectiveness of the system.

So I want to know which approach gives a boost in performance.

Calling a function and validating it using that or hard-coding IF statements and performing relevant validations?

Answer (score 3):

IMPO, if you guarantee you won't use IF statement (now and in the future) more than once, then it's fair enough to hardcode it.

However, if you couldn't guarantee that (which is almost always the case), invoking the function overhead is negligible. Specially if you compare that with the amount of work required to make any changes on they IF(s) as opposed to changing one function.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSj7zo_UfEs) by Steven Feuerstein explains hardcoding rather nicely

Comment: You're right, the overhead of calling a function is almost always irrelevant.  If it's not, then there's usually a design problem.  And for those extreme cases where it can't be refactored there's always the [`INLINE` pragma](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/inline_pragma.htm).